# Weak convergence of a sum of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Denote by $\mathcal{S}_{d-1}$ the unit simplex $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: x_i\in [0,1], i=1,..,d; \sum_{i=1}^dx_i=1 \}$. Then consider a sequence of random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$, $X_1,X_2,...$, and by the maps 
$$
f_n:\mathbb{R}^{kn}\mapsto \ell^\infty(\mathcal{S}_{d-1}),
$$

$$
g_n:\mathbb{R}^{kn}\mapsto \ell^\infty(\mathcal{S}_{d-1}),
$$
induce the sequences of stochastic processes 
$$
\{Y_n(t)\}_{t\in \mathcal{S}_{d-1}}=\{f_n(X_1,...X_n;t)\}_{t\in \mathcal{S}_{d-1}},
$$

$$
\{Z_n(t)\}_{t\in \mathcal{S}_{d-1}}=\{g_n(X_1,...X_n;t)\}_{t\in \mathcal{S}_{d-1}}.
$$

Suppose that we can prove that $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ converges weakly to continuous, tight stochastic processes $Y$ and $Z$, respectively. Then we can say that $Y_n+Z_n$ is asymptotically measurable and asymptotically tight. Also, from Prohorov's theorem we can claim that $Y_n+Z_n$ has a subsequence that converges to a tight Borel law.

Now, my question is: can we also conclude that $Y_n+Z_n$ weakly converges to some stochastic process (whatever it is) or not? Here I am interested in the existence of a limit rather then funding what such limit exactly is. Could anyone provide me any hint or reference in this regard?